# What are the similarities between MD and MC in the case of protein simulation?

Tags: molecular-dynamics, monte-carlo

As far as I understand, both MD and MC simulation methods use Force Fields.

Are there any other similarities between them?

Comment: That is certainly not true in general for Monte Carlo methods, many of which don't need to involve forces at all. So you might want to be more specific.

Comment: @Anyon, *So you might want to be more specific.* --- like what?

Comment: ...like specifying what type of Monte Carlo method(s) or application(s) you're asking about. (Which I guess you just did.)

Comment: @Anyon, *what type of Monte Carlo method* --- no specific type. This is a general question to understand the similarities between MD and MC.

Comment: Then I'd suggest you have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method or some other overview. My point is simply that the term "Monte Carlo" is *very* broadly applied to stochastic simulations with applications in a wide range of fields. Most of these are so wildly different from MD that comparisons seem pointless (see e.g. [Monte Carlo integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_integration) methods). But now that you've restricted the question to MC methods applied to protein simulations it might be well-defined.

Comment: @Anyon, so, are you going to write an answer, or is the last comment your final answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136482/discussion-between-anyon-and-user366312).

Comment: @Anyon not a huge problem, but as a site we [have tried to limit](https://mattermodeling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267/preserving-comments-and-chat-integration) the number of temporary chat rooms created. In the future, please redirect chat discussions to an existing related room.

Comment: I agree with Tyberius on that one. By the way @Anyon: Thanks so much for all your helpful answers, comments, and reviews over the last couple years here!